# buscar entre dos números en mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo una aplicación, que uso mongodb.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d70d9152cedd422e4cb648c"),
"budget" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d7129a926a0fe24084a80ca"),
        "price" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d714683576eb13114c93f80"),
                "pricea" : "5",
                "priceb" : "10"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d70d9152cedd422e4cb648c"),
"budget" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d7129a926a0fe24084a80ca"),
        "price" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d714683576eb13114c93f80"),
                "pricea" : "5",
                "priceb" : "10"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Necesito hacer una consulta que muestre todos los documentos, que existan entre los dos precios

Explicación: 
cada presupuesto tiene un rango de precio, **precioa**  y **preciob**
Un usuario necesita buscar un presupuesto con precioX.
Ese precio X tiene que existir entre (precioa y preciob)

***precio del usuario es 7, 
La consulta muestra los dos documentos, ya que el precio existe entre precioa y preciob***

¿Se puede hacer esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se tiene que poder, prueba con la query siguiente:

```
precio_usuario = 7

query = {'$and': [{'pricea': {'$lt': precio_usuario}},{'priceb': {'$gt': precio_usuario}}]}

df = db.collection.find(query)

for d in df:
    print(d)
```

Básicamente lo que le tienes que decir es que se tienen que cumplir las dos condiciones (and), que pricea sea menor (lt) que el precio_usuario, y que priceb ea mayor que el precio_usuario.

Yo lo he hecho con pymongo, pero la query que es lo que tu necesitas suele ser similar o igual (eso creo).
Si quisieras incluir el valor de 'pricea' si también es igual pon $lte (less than equal) y lo mismo con 'priceb' ($gte)

Comment: gracias, me sirvió , el problema ahora es que si son decenas, no funciona. solo funciona con unidades.

Comment: Que raro, creo que también debería funcionar. El problema es que no te está mostrando algunos que si debería mostrar? has comprobado que no sean tipo string?